# postfix - status=bounced (unknown user)

Tags: email, server, postfix-mta, dovecot

Good day,

I have a problem with the Postfix configuration in Debian 8. The thing is that when I want to send an email from test1@example.com to test2@example.com I get the following message:

> : to < test1@example.com >, relay = local, delay = 0.01, delays = 0/0/0, dsn = 5.1.1, status = bounced (unknown user: "test1")

And then leaves:

> : To < test2@example.com >, relay = local, delay = 0.01, delays = 0/0/0, dsn = 5.1.1, status = bounced (unknown user: "test2")

My configuration in /etc/postfix/main.cf:

[image]

I am using: Postfix, Dovecot and Debian 8

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ready! The problem was the configuration of the lmtp protocol, it had not enabled it. I followed the tutorial of this page https://appbead.com/blog/how-to-setup-mail-server-on-debian-8-jessie-with-postfix-dovecot-1.html

Comment: The link is dead. Could you elaborate on the solution changes?